# Edgeworthia crysantha Leaves drooping after heavy rain

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health

Last week here in England we had a lot of rain and Im concerned about the plant’s reaction. Can someone confirm if this is due to the rain and/or provide a solution to help the plant recover.

Thanks.[image: edgeworthia crysthantha]